# ECS Cluster (Fargate) with ALB, only the Service see something

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have deployed a basic web server with an ECS Cluster in FARGATE launch type, linked to an ALB, and i am now trying to understand how i am supposed to monitor the whole of it before performing some stress tests to see how everything react.

First of all, i want to make clear that i hit my app from the running task public IP (which may explain my following questions), not sure if it is what we are supposed to do to take advantage of the Cluster/ALB.

I am able to find some data in Cloudwatch, but a lot of services that offer a "metrics" tab just display empty graphs, so i am wondering if i do use the ALB when i reach my running task.

Here is what i don't understand:

When i go to ECS -> My Cluster -> My Service -> Metrics, i do see the Memory and CPU utilizations.

BUT

- When i go to ECS -> My Cluster -> Metrics, all the graphs are empty.
- When i go to EC2 -> Load Balancers -> My ALB -> Metrics, all the graphs are empty.
- When i go to EC2 -> Target Groups -> My Target Group -> Metrics, all the graphs are empty (except the Health Check).

Since it's a web server, i would like to set alerts on 4xx and 5xx HTTP responses, that kind of stuff, and i don't see where i could catch it regarding what AWS is tracing from my Stack (nothing but the ECS Service Memory/CPU utilization).

It looks like when i reach the ECS Running Task from its Public IP, the ECS Service supervise that well, but i don't go thought the ECS Cluster, neither the ALB (i feel like i am repeting myself but at least i am sure i am clear that way).

Is that possible i hit the Running Task without going thought the ALB first? If that's the reason, what are we supposed to hit?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read your question over and I can't figure out what exactly you're asking. Could you clean up your question a little so that it's more clear what the actual issue you're having is? I see 2 or 3 different potential questions currently.

Comment: Ok i'll do that, basically, i want to know why i don't see metrics in my ALB, Target Groups, and ECS Cluster. So i am wondering from where i am supposed to hit the service so the ALB can intercept hits and do its load balancing job

Comment: If you're running an ALB, why are you not hitting the ALB:`port` to get to your service? Why are you hitting your EC2 instance directly? That kind of defeats the purpose of having a LB.

Comment: I tried that in the first place but i get a timeout by doing that... I guess the ALB doesn't know how to route the incoming request. By the way i don't see any instance in my Target Group, i d'ont know if i should see something here with the FARGATE launch type.

Comment: If you can't hit your service via your ALB, that's why your ALB doesn't have any metrics.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? The target Group is well referenced on the ECS Service's Load Balancing section so it is well linked. Looks like everything is well configured.

Comment: I have found 1 instance in my Target Group, i figured the ECS service's Private IP is the same as the Instance in my Target Group, so i guess the service hit it directly. I am still wondering what i am supposed to hit, not sure it is the ALB DNS, it doesn't work still...